# How to convert event object to Json

Tags: python, arrays, json, amazon-web-services

I am finally getting data block from event but as object. How should we convert below object as Json using python.

**from**

```
May 16 09:11:19 ip-89-94-08-42 cloud-init: 16-05-2023 09:11:19.767 [pool-2028-thread-1] 
INFO com.github.vspiewak.loggenerator.SellRequest - id=3098, ip=89.59.44.09, email=client409@gmail.com, 
sex=F, brand=oreo, name=iMac, model=iMac - hjun 21 - juhs Pro, category=jukijheur, 
options=mhhjuian 21|Iris Pro, price=1299.0
```

**to :**

```
{

 "id": "3098",

 "ip": "89.59.44.09",

 "email": "client409@gmail.com",

 "sex": "F",

 "brand": "oreo",

 "name": "iMac",

 "model": "iMac - hjun 21 - juhs Pro",

 "category": "jukijheur",

 "options": "mhhjuian 21|Iris Pro",

 "price": "1299.0"

}
```

can anyone help me to get out of this ?

**Debugging:**

If i print the message:

```
spam = data['logEvents'][0]['message']
print(spam)
```

and it is printing:

```
May 16 14:08:45 ip-22-456-90-304 cloud-init: 16-05-2023 14:08:45.911 
[pool-19861-thread-1] 
INFO com.github.abcdswak.loggenerator.SearchRequest - id=201,ip=12.34.567.89,
category=Adeur, sex=F, brand=redme, color=Green
```

Comment: Expected output is NOT valid JSON

Comment: @buran apologies, updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only unnecessary information is isolated to the first entry, this is the easiest way.

```
toJson = dict(item.split("=") for item in data.split(", "))
```

And then remove the excess info in position 0:

```
value = list(toJson.keys())[0]
toJson[value[-2:]] = toJson.pop(value) #assuming position 0 will always be 'id'
```

---

Output: (Note: 'id' is moved, but still present.)

```
{"ip": "89.59.44.09", "email": "client409@gmail.com", "sex": "F", "brand": "oreo", "name": "iMac", "model": "iMac - hjun 21 - juhs Pro", "category": "jukijheur", "options": "mhhjuian 21|Iris Pro", "price": "1299.0", "id": "3098"}
```

You can `json.dumps()` this to get a JSON object.

---

***Example***

```
import json
data = "May 16 09:11:19 ip-89-94-08-42 cloud-init: 16-05-2023 09:11:19.767 [pool-2028-thread-1] INFO com.github.vspiewak.loggenerator.SellRequest - id=3098, ip=89.59.44.09, email=client409@gmail.com, sex=F, brand=oreo, name=iMac, model=iMac - hjun 21 - juhs Pro, category=jukijheur, options=mhhjuian 21|Iris Pro, price=1299.0"


toJson = dict(item.split("=") for item in data.split(", "))
value = list(toJson.keys())[0]
toJson[value[-2:]] = toJson.pop(value)

final = json.dumps(toJson)
print(final)
```

Comment: I have updated the data, Can you please have a look. sorry for the typo

Comment: What is the type of that data? String?

Comment: those are log messages from event. I used `json.loads()` to print the message

Comment: @Divya Okay, so it is a String object. Or at least you can convert `data['logEvents'][0]['message']` to a String.

Comment: yes it is a string object

Comment: Okay, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @SanguineL for the solution.
Is there any way to separate this Json output by new line characters (\n).

Comment: I do not see any newline characters in your code, so I do not have any idea how to proceed with that.